# std::function SIGILL_ILLOPC

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, std-function

I got some strange crash.

I cannot reproduce it, but it keeps reporting from customer

the platform is Arm64

gcc version is 6.4

the code is quite simple:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename F, typename ...Args>
Timer::registerTimerTask(T interval, F func, bool once, Args... args) {
    auto t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(interval);
    auto f = [=]() mutable {func(args...);};
    auto task = std::make_shared<Task>(f, t, once);
    addTask(task);
}
Task::Task(std::function<void()>func, std::chrono::nanoseconds timeout, bool once=false):
     mFunc(func), mTimeout(timeout), mOnce(once) {}
```

the code is quite simple, but on some customer's machine, it keeps crashing at constructor `Task::Task`, and it's `SIGILL_ILLOPC`

as far as I can understand, ILLOPC only happened when I have problem with cross-compiling, but this time it's not (since the same elf file works fine on others)

the stack is like:

```
Operating system: Linux
                  0.0.0 Linux 4.9.191 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 31 06:32:31 UTC 2022 aarch64
CPU: arm64
     4 CPUs

GPU: UNKNOWN

Crash reason:  SIGILL / ILL_ILLOPC
Crash address: 0x7f8e50dc14
Process uptime: not available

Thread 20 (crashed)
 0  myso.so!std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<Timer::registerTimerTask(T&&, F, bool, Args&& ...) [with T = std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> >&; F = Impl::socket(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, std::shared_ptr<Listener<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >)::<lambda()>; Args = {}]::<lambda()> >::_M_manager [functional : 1591 + 0x4]
     x0 = 0x0000007f6c002840    x1 = 0x0000007f767f5db8
     x2 = 0x0000000000000002    x3 = 0x0000007f8e50dc10
     x4 = 0x0000007f6c0054c0    x5 = 0x0000007f6c002b10
     x6 = 0x0000000000000000    x7 = 0x0000007f8cf633c0
     x8 = 0x0000007f767f5f48    x9 = 0x003b9aca00000000
    x10 = 0x0101010101010101   x11 = 0x0000000000000023
    x12 = 0x00000000767f6188   x13 = 0x00000003e8000000
    x14 = 0x0001ab437f192700   x15 = 0x00006e641756376a
    x16 = 0x0000007f8e56a618   x17 = 0x0000007f8e4eb91c
    x18 = 0x0000000000000000   x19 = 0x0000007f6c002830
    x20 = 0x0000007f6c002830   x21 = 0x0000007f767f5db8
    x22 = 0x0000000000000001   x23 = 0x0000007f767f6188
    x24 = 0x0000007f767f6137   x25 = 0x0000000000000003
    x26 = 0x0000000000800000   x27 = 0x0000000000000000
    x28 = 0x0000007f8c2a36f0    fp = 0x0000007f767f5cf0
     lr = 0x0000007f8e50eb0c    sp = 0x0000007f767f5cf0
     pc = 0x0000007f8e50dc14
    Found by: given as instruction pointer in context
 1  myso.so!Task::Task(std::function<void ()>, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >, bool) [task.h : 124 + 0x24]
    x19 = 0x0000007f6c002830   x20 = 0x0000007f6c002830
    x21 = 0x0000007f767f5db8   x22 = 0x0000000000000001
    x23 = 0x0000007f767f6188   x24 = 0x0000007f767f6137
    x25 = 0x0000000000000003   x26 = 0x0000000000800000
    x27 = 0x0000000000000000   x28 = 0x0000007f8c2a36f0
     fp = 0x0000007f767f5d20    sp = 0x0000007f767f5d40
     pc = 0x0000007f8e50e140
    Found by: call frame info
```

I really don't know why SIGILL would happen, and I can't find anyone with similar occasion

Comment: Look at the disassembly at the address given. Is there a legit ARM instruction? Is it a normal user-mode instruction? Does it exist in all CPU models?

Comment: @n.m. I checked that the program was running in root, and it's a normal ADD instruction

Comment: Processes owned by the root user don't have special privileges at the hardware level. Post the disassembly of the failed instruction and a few above and below it.